# Object reference error in Prepare() method of FastReport

Tags: asp.net, nullreferenceexception, fastreport

I am trying to create a .pdf file on a aspx link button.  Below is my code:

```
    protected void lbtnInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        List<InvoiceView> invoices = GetInvoices();

        FastReport.Utils.Config.WebMode = true;
        Report rep = new Report();
        var path = @"PathToDataFileToBeUsedByReport\Report.Data";
        rep.Load(path);
        rep.RegisterData(invoices, "Invoice", FastReport.Data.BOConverterFlags.AllowFields, 2);

        if (rep.Report.Prepare())    //Exception Thrown here!
        {
            FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport pdfExport = new FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport();
            pdfExport.ShowProgress = false;
            pdfExport.Subject = "Subject";
            pdfExport.Title = "xxxxxxx";
            pdfExport.Compressed = true;
            pdfExport.AllowPrint = true;
            pdfExport.EmbeddingFonts = true;

            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
            rep.Report.Export(pdfExport, strm);
            rep.Dispose();
            pdfExport.Dispose();
            strm.Position = 0;

            return File(strm, "application/pdf", "report.pdf");
        }
    }
```

But the exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is thrown on `rep.Report.Prepare()`

Any help is really appreciated.

Edit: I get the same error when I replace `rep.Report.Prepare()` with `rep.Prepare()`, in which case I know `rep` is not null.

Comment: My guess is that `rep.Report` is null. Try debugging and find out.

Comment: Thanks but it's not a duplicate. I get the error on `rep.Export(blabla)` too, and clearly, `rep` is not null

Comment: Before you ask on StackOverflow, you need to *use the debugger* and find out what's null. Until you've done that and shared the results, it is very much a duplicate.

Comment: I have used the debugger, but I can't step into FastReport's dll